# Save editables to variable and then print

Tags: php, pimcore

I am currently exploring pimcore and its editables. So I want to have a dynamic list with social media icons that is editable in the backend. I created a snippet.

So I am using the block editable like this:

```
<?php

while ($this->block("social-media")->loop()) {

  if($this->editmode) {

    print $this->link('social-media-link');
    print $this->image('social-media-icon', [ 'width' => 30, 'height' => 30 ]);

  }
  else {

    print "<a href=\"{$this->link('social-media-link')->getHref()}\">{$this->image('social-media-icon', [ 'width' => 30, 'height' => 30 ])}</a>";

  }

}
```

This works as expected. But now I want to get rid of the duplication. To achive this, I tried this:

```
<?php

while ($this->block("social-media")->loop()) {

  $objCurrentSocialMediaLink = $this->link('social-media-link');
  $objCurrentSocialMediaIcon = $this->image('social-media-icon', [ 'width' => 30, 'height' => 30 ]);

  if($this->editmode) {

    print $objCurrentSocialMediaLink;
    print $objtCurrentSocialMediaIcon;

  }
  else {

    print "<a href=\"{$objCurrentSocialMediaLink->getHref()}\">{$objCurrentSocialMediaIcon}</a>";

  }

}
```

But this does not work. The backend renders only the link editable. Does anyone know why and what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not printing the correct variable. Remove the "t" in this variable:

`print $objtCurrentSocialMediaIcon;`

Should be:

`print $objCurrentSocialMediaIcon;`

Comment: No worries, happened to all of us in the past :) It would maybe make sense to invest in an IDE like PhpStorm - the IDE will very clearly show you such errors and you can save a lot of time by not debugging such typing errors, which happen quite often.

Comment: Yes, I guess you are right. Is there any way to force pimcore to show such errors in development/debugging mode? Is there support for such thing?